# Differences between input commands in Python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python, text, input, python-3.x

Ok, so i use a lot of input commands, and I understood that in Python2 I can do:

```
text = raw_input ('Text here')
```

But now that i use Python 3 I was wondering what's the difference between:

```
text = input('Text here')
```

and:

```
text = eval(input('Text here'))
```

when do I have to use the one or the other?

Comment: If you weren't used to using `eval`, long story short it evaluates the string you pass to it as if it was code.

Comment: If you never use `eval()`, that's probably OK. If you do use `eval()`, never use it on unsanitized user input. Consider what happens if the user types `os.system("rm -rf /")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `raw_input` became `input` and Python 2.x's `input` was removed.  So, by doing this in 3.x:

```
text = input('Text here')
```

you are basically doing this in 2.x:

```
text = raw_input('Text here')
```

Doing this in 3.x:

```
text = eval(input('Text here'))
```

is the same as doing this in 2.x:

```
text = input('Text here')
```

Here is a quick summary from the Python Docs:

> PEP 3111: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the new `input()`
>   function reads  a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing
>   newline stripped. It raises  `EOFError` if the input is terminated
>   prematurely. To get the old behavior of `input()`,  use `eval(input())`.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know what's the difference between raw_input and input in Python 2.x. Can you tell to me?

Comment: `raw_input` simply reads what the user types in and returns it as a string.  `input` on the other hand evaluates what the user types in as real Python code (note that this is in 2.x).

Answer (score 2):

These are equivalent:

```
raw_input('Text here')       # Python 2
input('Text here')           # Python 3
```

And these are equivalent:

```
input('Text here')           # Python 2
eval(raw_input('Text here')) # Python 2
eval(input('Text here'))     # Python 3
```

Notice that in Python 3 there isn't a function called `raw_input()`, as Python's 3 `input()` is just `raw_input()` renamed. And in Python 3 there isn't a direct equivalent of Python 2's `input()`, but it can be easily simulated like this: `eval(input('Text here'))`.

Now, in Python 3 the difference between `input('Text here')` and `eval(input('Text here'))` is that the former returns the string representation of the input entered (with trailing newline removed), whereas the latter unsafely [*evaluates*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) the input, as if it were an expression entered directly in the interactive interpreter.