# Send the user an error message when they input anything apart from 4, 6 or 12

Tags: python

In the following code, I want to add something that sends the user an error message when they input anything apart from 4, 6 or 12:

```
import random
dice = input("""Hello there!
Welcome to the dice roll simulator.
There are three types of dice which you can roll:
a 4 sided die, a 6 sided die and a 12 sided die.
Please enter either 4,6 or 12 depending on which die you would like to roll.""")

if dice : 4 or 6 or 12
print("You have rolled a " + dice + " sided dice, with the result of : " +    str((random.randrange(1,int(dice)))))
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Conditional_Statements
additionally, it looks like `input` returns a string
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: you'll want to convert the result of input to an integer first: `dice = int(dice)`

Comment: I think I've never before seen this many duplicate answers on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `else` statement.

I'd recommend you to do a basic python tutorial before starting to ask questions here.

```
dice = int(dice)

if dice in {4, 6, 12}:
    print("..." + str(dice))
else:
    print("error message")
```

Comment: Why a set and not a tuple here? (Will do the same thing just never seen anyone write it this way.)

Comment: Well, for 3 elements the lookup will probablybe slower... It's just my code style.

Comment: probably hashing for the set would take longer. Tuples are faster than lists in this context (from what I've read)

Comment: @WayneWerner: Yup. But if you're coding python, you should simply not worry about such things. That's for when you're writing `C`.

Comment: It's maybe a little clearer, though. I mean we really mean "if the results are not in the set containing 4, 6, and 12", not some ordered triple or however you would normally interpret a 3-tuple.

Comment: @mic_e, I'd say that's not the best advice. You shouldn't go through your code base replacing all `... in [...]` with tuples, but it *is* something you should be aware of. And if you get into the habit of just using `()` in these cases then everyone wins. But maybe that's what you meant? ;)

Comment: Python should be fun to write, intuitive to write, and easy to read. It is also designed to look very much like mathematical expressions (more so than any other popular language I'm aware of). `C` code on the other hand should be optimized the hell out of. In the end, just use what you're used to, and stop worrying about details such as how many hash functions will be called during that statement.

Comment: import random
dice = input("""Hello there!
Welcome to the dice roll simulator.
There are three types of dice which you can roll:
a 4 sided die, a 6 sided die and a 12 sided die.
Please enter either 4,6 or 12 depending on which die you would like to roll.""")
dice = int(dice)
if dice in {4, 6, 12}:
    print("You have rolled a " + dice + " sided dice, with the result of : " + str((random.randrange(1,int(dice)))))
else:
    print("What you have entered is invalid. Please enter either 4, 6 or 12. Thank you")
Doesn't seem to be working? and I have tried to use else and elif before but they haven't

Comment: Ouch. Please post that code on pastebin. In python, spaces, indentations and newlinesare extremely important. Don't say `it doesn't work`, post the error message.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that; as you can obviously tell I am really not code savvy :P

Comment: when I input 4 I am given this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computing Science\Computing science A453\Task 1\Design\task 1 code.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("You have rolled a " + dice + " sided dice, with the result of : " + str((random.randrange(1,int(dice)))))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Just go to http://pastebin.com or a similar site, paste your code into the text field, and click `Submit`. It's not just for coding, it's for *everything* that has to do with text.

Comment: You need to cast `dice` to `str` in the first message.

Answer (score 1):

```
if dice in (4, 6, 12):
    print("...")
else:
    print("error")
```

This is more pythonic than what I had earlier, but you should remember that `or` in Python doesn't work as intuitively as you might think; that is, `x == 6 or 7` must be written as `x == 6 or x == 7`

As noted below, if you're using `input()` in Python 2.x, you don't have to cast it to an int but if you're using `raw_input()` in 2.x or `input()` in 3.x, you do have to cast, or else it will result in a `TypeError`.

Edit: Since you're using input, you're going to have to cast it to an int because `input` will return a string.

As Two-Bit Alchemist noted, in Python 2.x, `raw_input()` is equivalent to `input()` in Python 3.x.

`input()` in Python 2.x is equivalent to `eval(input())` in Python3.x

For the differences in the input types in Python 2.x vs 3.x, see [Differences between input commands in Python 2.x and 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036188/differences-between-input-commands-in-python-2-x-and-3-x)

Comment: Depends on Python2/Python3. Python2 tries to _eval_ the return value of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused as to what `:` means.

`:` means this line is the beginning of a block, and the next line(s) are either indented (4 spaces, please), or it's all on 1 line.

What you have written (`4 or 6 or 12`) actually evaluates those numbers in the boolean context. Since in Python any non-0 number is True this actually evaluates to: `True or True or True`.

Of course that does nothing, it's just sitting there - because `if dice:` is actually where it was evaluated.

What you might want is `if dice in (4, 6, 12):...`