# Getting Different O/P on python2.7 & python 3.5

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm just a beginner in python.
I was just writing some code to print table of any number and I surprisingly got different answers on python v2.7 & python v3.5!
This occur only when I use string function, not when I use comma(,).

[image: Screenshot of both terminals]

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The difference in output is due to the difference between Python 2 `input` and Python3 `input`.

Comment: The `input` function is very different for python2 and python3, you should read the docs

Comment: Refer the usage of `input` in Python2 and Python3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between raw\_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: See [Differences between input commands in Python 2.x and 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036188/differences-between-input-commands-in-python-2-x-and-3-x). BTW, you should concentrate on learning Python 3. Once you're comfortable with that, you can go back and learn about the differences between Python 3 & Python 2, if you really need to. Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, now I got the real reason of this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the type of 'n'. It is treated as an integer than you get the numeric operation '*', in the other case it is treated as string with the string operation '*'.  Try out type(n) after you read it and you will see the difference.

Comment: I got to know that it was because of the input function! it have difference in Python 3.x & 2.x